# noun adjective sentence pattern

Tags: grammar

最近は海外旅行より、国内の温泉旅行やスキー旅行の方が若いカップルに人気です。   why we use 若いカップルに人気です. Noun に adjective, what does it mean ??
can anyone explain this sentence pattern ??

Answer (score 3):

This に is an equivalent of the English preposition 'to' used with certain adjectives, as in:

- 彼**に**も難しい問題
  a problem that is difficult also **to** him
- 私**に**は健康が重要です。
  **To** me, health is the important thing.

In English, I think people usually say "popular among young couples" rather than "popular to young couples". But in Japanese, we can safely use に with 人気. You have to memorize "popular among X" translates to "Xに人気".